# What does the underscore translate function do in my code without a textdoman

Tags: localization, xgettext

I am hooking into `comment_form_default_fields` doing some heavy string replacements.

There are translated strings like `__( 'Name' )` in there. I need the text.

I have two or three different ways to solve this.

1. I could just use my own text domain, but that would mean I have to provide my own translation for my code, do not like that. Especially because I just reuse already translated strings.
2. Extract the text (with regex). Better but not a huge fan either.
3. Just use the same words `__( 'Name' )` as in core without textdomain?

The translation is done by lines in files to some extent I think, but when lines change the translations do not suddenly stop to work correctly, but I think there can be different translation for the same world, and it will pick the right ones. If the translation is properly done.

My question is what actually happens when I use no domain? Will it work at all? Will it just pull the first translation for a word it can find in WP core?

Answer (score 3):

In the [`__()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/), it says

> If there is no translation, or the text domain isn’t loaded, the original text is returned.

Also, if you don't provide a textdomain, then `'default'` is used.

So, essentially, `__( 'Name' )` will try to find a translation in the `'default'` domain, and, failing that, return `'Name'`.

If you *do* provide your own textdomain (eg `__( 'Name', 'my-plugin-text-domain' )`) but no translations, then the untranslated string will be used. There is, as far as I know, no downside to this, and it has the upside of making your theme or plugin translatable by you or others who wish to do it in the future.

Comment: You did not fully answer my questions. So I assumed right, it will just use the first translation it finds  in core `default`. But if on core `__( 'Name' )` name is in two different  files and has two _separate_ and _different_ translations. The right one based file+ line will be used I think.

Comment: And you are wrong, there are two downsides to using my own domain. You listed them. I have to translate it, and if I do not, there will be just the English string returned. How is that "no downside" ? I will use no domain because the string is already translated in core, no point in using my own domain for an already translated string the probably has no different translations anyway. It may even be that core needs a context for that.

Comment: You don't *have* to translate the strings at all; but using `__()` allows you *or others* to add translations to your theme at any time. Also, if you have strings that might need different translations in different contexts, you can use [`_x()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_x/) instead of `__()`.

Comment: No, I do not mean `_x()` I do think you are not getting it. I am not sure if I misunderstood you wrong, but It seems to me you said that using my own domain has no downsides. It does. Why would I not translate? No clue why you're bringing that up, as it's the worst thing of all to do.

Comment: "If there is no translation, or the text domain isn’t loaded, the original text is returned." still does not answer if it's used in 3rd party code if It will be just pick the 1st best translation from core, I think it will. And it's still unclear to me how the function actually works when it comes to .php files and lines.